# Choose local video and play it in HTML5 videoplayer (all local, same folder)

Tags: javascript, html, video, filechooser

for school I need to use a HTML5 videoplayer with extra controls and the option to choose a file from local drive. The page runs local, too. So it is not uploaded. The files (HTML and video) are in the same local folder.

For the choose-thing I use a form with `<form><input type="file" id="chosen" /><button type="submit" onclick="open();">Change</button></form>`. Now here is my JavaScript that should manipulate the source of the videoplayer:

```
function open()
{
    var file=document.getElementById('chosen');
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    player.src=fileURL;
    player.load();
}
```

The videoplayer looks like this:

```
<video id=player>
<source src="big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="trailer_480p.mov" type"video/mp4" />
</video>
```

and of course I have connected the variable "player" with my videoplayer. The player.load()-thing works properly, so the function gets called correctly.

Now my question: What's wrong or missing in the Javascript-Part? The project doesn't work as explained.

Maybe you can help me. Thanks ;)

Comment: Are you checking in FF or some other browser?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a hurry. So the question is how the JavaScript can manipulate the source-tag of the video. Video and HTML-File are in the same folder, locally. I'm checking in IE9 and FF

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but there are some issues in your script.

```
function openPlayer(){ // open() is a native function, don't override
  var vplayer=document.getElementById('player'); // A reference to the video-element
  var file=document.getElementById('chosen').files[0]; // 1st member in files-collection
  var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  vplayer.src=fileURL;
  vplayer.load();
  return; // A good manner to end up a function
}
```

And don't forget to change function's name in `onclick()`.

More info about `<video>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/video

Especially for scripting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLMediaElement

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the absence of codec is causing a problem here, you video source url should look something like this:

```
<source src="big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
```