# How to play client side stored video (.flv/mp4/.ogv) on aspx web page using C# 4.0 compatible to all browsers?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, cross-browser, media-player, flash

i want to play video of above any format on aspx web page. actually i'm using microsoft visual 10 and C# 4.0 for it. i'm not bother about player or plugins or anything. using this scripts and video tag of html5 now video is playing fine on Mozilla as well as Chrome. but how to play video on IE using HTML5? Is there any solution?

```
 <script src="http://html5media.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/jquery.html5media.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245090/choose-local-video-and-play-it-in-html5-videoplayer-all-local-same-folder

Comment: actually now its working on Mozilla too. i used one java script and html5 tag for that. but now video is not playing on IE; that's the problem. how to achieve it? see my modified ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html5 `<video>` tag is not supported on IE8 and before. It is only supported on IE9+ and on IE9, the support is limited to mp4 videos only. ref. http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/video

For unsupported versions, you might need to use a plugin like Windows Media Player or Flash.